# Importing classes from Mallet in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, import, mallet

I am trying to use the Mallet api for Java. However, I cannot import anything.

Adding external jars to the classpath in eclipse doesn't seem to do anything. Copying mallet.jar and mallet-deps.jar into a lib file and adding internal jar has also failed.

Mallet has installed properly, and may be run from the command line without issue.

The specific error occurs when I try

```
import cc.mallet.types.*;
```

and eclipse says that "The import cc cannot be resolved."

Am I missing something? Is there something else I can try?

Comment: Is your project using maven, gradle or something like that?

Comment: No, I am not using any of those

Answer (score 2):

1. Try removing all the mallet jars from your project.
2. Create a mallet.jar file using the instructions from the MALLET documentation site.http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/download.php
3. Now, add these mallet.jar & mallet-deps.jar(present inside dist/ directory of mallet folder) in Project->Properties->Java Build Path-> Libraries Tab-> Add external JARS.
4. Click Apply and OK.
5. Now, try to build your project again. Hope it works!